# Simple HTTP parser in C stops working after a few rounds

Tags: c

I am trying to parse a simple html that retrieved by socket. I've just been using C for two weeks, still in the process of getting myself familiar with the language, especially the memory control stuff.

This is the parser I've made, a very simple one:

```
char *parser(const char *buf, int size, char end_token) {
    char *content = malloc((size_t) size);
    memset(content, 0, sizeof content);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        char next = *(buf + i);
        if (next == end_token) break;
        *(content + i) = next;
    }
    return content;
}
```

and this is how I use it: whenever I get a new page, I do the following process to get the URLs:

```
while (1) {
    buf = strstr(buf, "<a href=");
    if (buf == NULL) {
        break;
    } else {
        buf = buf + strlen("<a href=");
        char *url = parser(buf, 100, '>');
        url = strstr(url, "9780") + strlen("9780");
        char *url_page = parser(url, 50, '\"');
    }
}
```

Suppose this is the content I want to parse (content in `buf`), repeatedly parsing it, after a couple times, the return of parser is going to broke. What's the reason cause that broke? What can I do to prevent such break?

```
<html>
<body>
This is page ##
Other pages here include 
<a href="http://32.65.194.40:9780/100/20.html">This one</a>
and probably a few others</a>
</body>
</html>
```

My returns for url:

```
1st round: "http://32.65.194.40:9780/100/20.html"
2nd round: "http://32.65.194.40:9780/100/20.html"
...
n round: "http://32.65.194.40:9780/100/20.html" IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0�
```

Comment: Third line, first severe bug: `memset(content, 0, sizeof content);` -- this is the size of a pointer.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to look at the values of variables in the good and bad cases?

Comment: you need to be sure that your content string ends with \0 char, as @FelixPalmen mentioned `sizeof content` will return size of the pointer type, so you need to use again `(size_t) size`, and do not forget to free your memory to avoid memory leaks

Comment: Thanks, that's a severe mistake! As @IvanIgnatiev-MSFT commented, memory leaks. If I put all retrieved urls in another container pointer, i.e., `collections`, for later use, do I need to loop `collections` to free every subfields after use?

Comment: @GabrielChu in C you need to manage memory by yourself, in C++ you have more options with smart pointers etc., but I do not suggest to mix C and C++, in C++ use string objects to manipulate with your string and not `char*` (or incapsulate `char*` in your custom string class with proper destructor)